# file Explorer wait too long in Android studio and IntelliJ

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, filepath, explorer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oNzT.png)

Hi. I'm so tired cause this problem.

I'm using Android Studio 4.2.1

---

Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7351085, built on May 11, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by N/A
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M

---

I didn't wait When i Open project.
Because File Explorer worked precisely and quickly.
but when days ago, It's too late and make me wait and make me tired.
i'm using samsung evo 960 nvme, and i have 32g ram, and use Ryzen 5 3600
It's not Computer Specifications.
Even IntelliJ is same.
but other Explorer worked right.
before Incident, i installed old build toos for old source. i didn't do anything Other than that.
and One of project is too late when build and run.
i don't know why.
Just before i'm clean Android studio and clean Install. but it's Stil do not working properly.

i need help.

Comment: In your image C:/ is missing. That W with dash is not proper path to load. I guess slash is missing.

Comment: Is it possible to share logs folder zipped (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) after reproducing the issue?

Comment: @VirajS Hi. Sry but i can see well. i don't know how i can show that. that's Image about when Click 'File - Open..' (:Open File or Project = i mean File Explorer ) in android studio. in there .. Loading is too long....

Comment: @y.bedrov well... it doesn't show log... just When click 'File - Open... ', Loading is too long. I should wait for see my directory

Comment: You may find logs using File Manager. Logs will indicate why there is a delay in opening. As a blind guess - do you have any network mounts?

Comment: @y.bedrov How can i find logs?  
     https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tj_JOwrr9ggUZhRWDBDrgkWQqnwotw3d/view?usp=sharing    This is my mean problem. And i don't have network drive.

Comment: "Help | Show Log in..." should open folder with logs.

Comment: @y.bedrov I'm sorry for the late reply. and I appreciate your effort for me. I found a way about this problem and another problem that gradle build and install app too slow. I guess that cause gradle version. i thought that i didn't change gradle ver, but when i reinstall android studio, Likewise  'Android SDK Build - tool ' has been reinstalled.